# Organizing a git repo that belongs inside another repo

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm currently trying to get two git repos up and running. One for front-end and one for back-end.

The front-end app uses an API supplied by the 'back-end' but currently I supply a dummy API (which are just json files) under subfolder '/api'. This approach works well because it saves front-end developers from having to setup any databases and server-side stuff.

As for the back-end, since it resides within the front-end app - I'm finding it difficult to figure out how to track the back-end as well, whilst being able to plug it into the front-end app for testing etc. Ideally when developing the back-end, the front-end would always be there in its newest state.

I've seen sub-modules and subtrees mentioned but I'm also fairly new to git and don't want to dive too deep just yet.

edit: the directory structure is very simple, just:

**app/...** - everything in here should be tracked by the front-end repo, although the 'api/' folder is just a mock back-end.

**app/api/...** - everything back-end related. Since the folder must be public and I don't want to use a sub-domain.

Comment: What would be the problem with having a separate git repo for the front and back end?  Can you list your directory structure, clearly showing where the front and back end code resides?

Comment: I presume the reason for the question is that if the OP uses two repos, he will need to manually sync the API folder between the two.

Comment: If you don't want to use submodules you should make frontend and backend reside in separate folders and handle them with separate repositories. You could always move to a submodule later on using those 2 existing repos.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've added the structure. I suppose I want the front-end to be up to date for testing the back-end but since it surrounds the back-end it's not simply a case of two separate folders.

Answer (score 1):

I presume the issue is that you don't want to have to manually sync the API folder between the two, i.e. you don't want two separate repos with duplicated information.

I think your options here are:

- Use two repos, automate copying the API folder (e.g. rsync). Assume that they are cloned as siblings into one directory and make "make apiupdate" (or similar) do the same thing.
- Investigate submodules (which you don't want to do)
- Put everything in one repo, but use separate directories, and possibly a symlink for the API folder. Ensure your makefiles etc. remain independent. This means 'too much gets cloned' for a developer only working on one project, but git is nice and fast.
- As above, but attempt to accelerate it by using subtrees (which you don't want to do).